# CentOS, KVM, VLANs and bridging

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge, centos7

I need help designing networking for virtualized guests using KVM. My machine is running CentOS 7 and has 2 NICs. I'd like to achieve the following

- One physical interface (em1) shall be used for host access only. The host will have a pretty normal configuration with untagged traffic and a static IP address.
- The other physical interface (em2) receives tagged traffic for different VLANs.
- The virtual machines shall only see the traffic for their specific VLAN. Inter-Guest communication is not required to be done within the KVM.
- I would prefer the traffic on the virtual NIC to be untagged, to make sure that the guest doesn't change its internal NIC config to spoof other networks.

[Link to concept graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VeJU.png)

I am new to libvirt and also not used to Network Manager. I searched for documentation but found conflicting information, starting with the question whether it is possible to configure this bridging via network manager. I also read about the possibility to let the KVM do the switching.

I would be grateful for either direct configuration help or a pointer to an up-to-date documentation that does not use (on CentOS 7) deprecated tools or workarounds for problems removed in the meantime.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you switch to Proxmox? It provides all of your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want, while usefull, is not very straighfoward to do. Basically, you have 3 possibilities:

1. use the Open vSwitch stack to virtualize the bridge/switch
2. use dedicated software bridge for each vlan
3. on recent kernels it is possible to use the ["bridge VLAN filter"](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/BRIDGE_VLAN_FILTERING.html) feature to have a single "intelligent" bridge to rule them all

*Solution n.1* is (probably) the most complete, but the most difficult to setup.

*Solution n.2* is what I adopted for my lab test. For example, for VLAN 10 and 20, you had do create a similar setup:

```
eth0 (physical interface) -> eth0.10 (VLAN tagged) -> br10 (bridge with eth0.10 and the relative virtual qemu/kvm interface)
eth0 (physical interface) -> eth0.20 (VLAN tagged) -> br20 (bridge with eth0.20 and the relative virtual qemu/kvm interface)
```

Please note that if you need to have untagged traffic also on the tagged bridge, you **must** issue the following ebtables rule:
`ebtables -t broute -A BROUTING -i eth0 -p 802.1Q -j DROP`
This rule is needed due to how the Linux networking stack manage incoming packets. For more information, see [here](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/vms-vlans-and-bridges-oh-my-part-2/), [here](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/misc/brnf-faq.html) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/414115/linux-vlans-over-bridge)

*Solution n.3* should be the clever one, but you need kernel support for it (and libvirt also). CentOS7 should have a sufficient recent kernel, but I don't know if all other software pieces are ready.

*Solution n.4* (bonus one): if you don't need guest/host communication, give a look at the macvtap driver. While I don't use it, you should be able to setup a similar solution:

```
eth0 (physical interface) -> eth0.10 (VLAN tagged) -> MAC vtap on eth0.10
eth0 (physical interface) -> eth0.20 (VLAN tagged) -> MAC vtap on eth0.20
```

For me, the impossibility to communicate from/to guest/host is too much of a limitation, but your requirement may be different.

Finally, have a look [here](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/LinuxConJapan2014_makita_0.pdf), it's worth reading.